# Does loose leaf tea need a hechsher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification

Sometimes I find bags of dried tea leaves of various sorts in my local Turkish store. Do such teas need a hechsher (certification as kosher)? Is there any indicator I can use to tell if it's kosher or not?

Obviously this assumes there is no hechsher on the packaging.

Comment: Are they from israel?

Comment: @DoubleAA, probably Turkey or India.

Comment: There's a vote to close as a request for p'sak....this one is on the fence (I think), but is OK even though there is a back-story in the first person.

Comment: @Shokhet, the actual question is posed in general form. I agree with you. The back-story provides motivation. The only thing I might change would be to substitute "one" for "I" in the second question.

Comment: "How can I tell if this is kosher" isn't p'sak; "is this thing with ambiguous circumstances kosher" might be (depending on the rest of the question).  I think this is fine.

Comment: y would a flower need a hechsher

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/coffee_and_tea_pesach.php):

> Black, green, white, yellow, oolong, and jasmine tea are all inherently kosher for Pesach, but the issues of decaffeination and flavoring apply to tea in the same way that they apply to coffee.  For that reason all decaffeinated tea and all flavored tea (which includes most herbal teas) should only be used on Pesach if they bear an appropriate Pesach certification.

If it doesn't require certification for Pesach, it certainly doesn't for the rest of the year. And if it requires for Pesach, it may require for the rest of the year. Certainly the flavors are always a matter of concern all year round.

*Note: This is a very American centric answer, but your profile says you are from Brooklyn, so it would seem to apply to you.*