# Is making Matcha on shabbat allowed?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

[Matcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matcha) is made from steamed tea leaves that are ground to a powder.

It is prepared by placing 1 teaspoon of matcha powder into a ceramic bowl (Kli Sheni) and taking water that is kept at 80°C (176°F) in a Kli Rishon and pouring 30 ml down the side of the bowl, not directly onto the powder whisking the matcha and the adding 90 ml of water pouring it down the side of the bowl.

Would this be, halachically speaking, mutar on Shabbat? I think this would be a case of [ain bishul acher bishul](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bishul#Ein_Bishul_Achar_Bishul:%7E:text=fire.%5B4%5D-,Ein%20Bishul%20Achar%20Bishul,-There%20is%20a), the steaming being the first bishul.

Comment: Does this help? https://dinonline.org/2021/08/10/coffee-or-tea-on-shabbat/#_ftn1

Comment: Thank you, but I've already seen that page.  The Halacha on the page is useful, but the metziut is different enough that I don't know if it applies.

Comment: First of all [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) D and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: There is a bishul after bishul for things that are very easy to cook, tea is one example of it. I also don't understand how pouring water down the side helps. Is your case not similar to pouring water from kli rishon straight onto the tea, which is forbidden?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104496

Comment: what temperature are the leaves steamed to?

Comment: @mblock First off matcha is not the same as most tea. With other teas they are roasted not steamed, so you have bishul acher tzeliya. The reason the halacha is not to pour directly out of kli rishon is becuse of the temperature, but in this case the temperature in the kli rishon is already as cool as pouring boiled water into a kli sheni. The reason to we pour down the side when making matcha is to further cool it, again is the difference in temperature is similar to pouring from the kli rishon into a kli sheni then from the kli sheni directly onto the matcha.

Comment: Traditional matcha preparation is very focused on not cooking the matcha, thats why we are strict about the temperature not being above 80°C

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy,  The tea leaves are steamed for 1-2 minutes, I would guess that they reach more than 80°C (176°F)